# How to get metrics data for only Instagram Ad Campaigns from Facebook Ad Account using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

How do I fetch only Instagram Ad Campaigns instead of all Ad Campaigns from Facebook Graph API.

Here is what I have tried till now.

```
var url = https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/"+ad_account_id+"/insights?fields=spend,
 clicks,impressions,account_currency,actions&breakdowns=publisher_platform
```

When I make a request to the above URL, I'm getting all Campaigns data. How do I create the URL to request only Instagram Ad Campaigns?

Comment: Have you tried the `filtering` parameter? (I assume some of the fields exposes the info that this an IG ad campaign to begin with?)

Comment: That's the filter I'm unable to figure out. I tried something like this `breakdowns=publisher_platform{instagram}`. But I was getting invalid formation errors.

Comment: I guess you need a field name, not a breakdown. Is there any field in the result that indicates the platform was instagram?

Comment: @04FS nothing I could find. Here is their documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters

Comment: Yeah, I had a look over those already, but couldn’t spot anything platform related. Maybe try and ask for more fields than you are doing with what’s shown above, and then check if any of the data you get allows to make that determination?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found a solution like the one below. you can check it now using Facebook API v14

```
<your act account>/insights?fields=inline_link_clicks,impressions,reach,frequency,ctr,cost_per_inline_link_click,spend&breakdowns= publisher_platform,platform_position&level=account
```